# How to set the project name/group/version, plus {source,target} compatibility in the same file?

Tags: java, gradle

I intend to generalize the use of gradle for my projects and would like to reuse the same build file everywhere. Unfortunately, I have trouble trying to define the properties mentioned in $subject in a single file, in order to ease the migration.

This is gradle 1.6.

What I have tried, failing at all attempts:

- `gradle.properties`: cannot modify name (read only, have to use a `settings.gradle` and override the *root* project name!); `{source,target}Compatibility` not taken into account;
- `settings.gradle`: `{source,target}Compatibility` not taken into account either!

So, what is the correct method to achieve this? What I have tried so far in `gradle.properties`:

```
group = something
name = whatever  # cannot do!
version = whatever
sourceCompatibility = whatever # not taken into account!
```

And in `settings.gradle`:

```
sourceCompatibility = "whatever";  # not taken into account!
```

**EDIT** Well, the "name" problem just cannot be solved; for the rest, I have used another file which I apply in the build file. The "name" handling really isn't right :/

**EDIT 2** This is now 2014 and gradle 1.12, and the problem still is not solved...

Comment: FYI, the inability to customize the project name in the build.gradle file is currently an improvement request: http://issues.gradle.org//browse/GRADLE-2412.

Answer (score 144):

gradle.properties:

```
theGroup=some.group
theName=someName
theVersion=1.0
theSourceCompatibility=1.6
```

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = theName
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"

group = theGroup
version = theVersion
sourceCompatibility = theSourceCompatibility
```

Comment: So you want to reuse across builds? You can do `apply from: "other.gradle"` or `apply from: "http://my.server.com/other.gradle"`. Note that the latter isn't currently cached. To get caching, you'd have to write a *binary* plugin.

Comment: Yes, I use the `apply from:` solution; however this does not solve the name problem :(

Comment: I think in latest Gradle you can apply a plugin in `settings.gradle` as well. However, it seems a bit odd to use a plugin to set the same project name across builds.

Comment: Note that it's also possible to set all these properties from an `init.gradle` in your user home (see user guide).

Comment: Well, the intent is not to have the same project name for all projects ;) But I'd like to have only one file to modify in order to set the name/version/other stuff. Right now, because of `name`, there are two :(

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve/optimize for. For example, you could have a properties file and make settings.gradle/build.gradle read values from there.

Comment: Well, I've tried... With all the problems mentioned in the question above, and more!

Comment: Chances are you didn't do it right, but since you didn't provide any details/code, I can't really tell.

Comment: You don't have to define variables in gradle.properties and use in settings.gradle .  You can just mention in settings.gradle   rootProject.name = "someName".  Make sure to specify it in double quotes in settings.gradle.

Comment: what about packaging? (AAR for instance)

Comment: The need for a `settings.gradle` file is less than ideal for multi-project builds.

Comment: @GopinathM.R what about singlequotes ? `rootProject.name = 'someName'` it work fine for me !

Answer (score 27):

I found the solution to a similar problem. I am using Gradle 1.11 (as April, 2014).  The project name can be changed directly in `settings.gradle` file as following:

```
  rootProject.name='YourNewName'
```

This takes care of uploading to repository (Artifactory w/ its plugin for me) with the correct artifactId.

Comment: This solution is less than ideal for multi-project builds.

Comment: @asandroq, as you can only have a single settings file, you will have to rename sub module from there. It's central, but it works.

Comment: Renaming subprojects looks like `project(":lib").name = "shared"`, and then you need to use the new name in sister projects e.g. `implementation(project(":shared"))`.
Weirdly, the old name can't be used for e.g. `gradle :lib:build` on the command-line, but IDEA won't let you use the new name.

Answer (score 20):

I set the artifact baseName so it is independent of the build project name, which allows me to achieve what you want:

```
jar {
    baseName "core"
}
```

With this property set, even if my project name is "foo", when I run `gradle install`, the artifact is published with the name `core` instead of `foo`.

Comment: Does not help all other tasks that would be using the project name, and may create additional confusion over the clashing names...

Answer (score 6):

Apparently this would be possible in `settings.gradle` with something like this.

```
rootProject.name = 'someName'
gradle.rootProject {
    it.sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
}
```

I recently received advice that a project property can be set by using a closure which will be called later when the Project is available.

Answer (score 0):

use buildSrc with Gradle Kotlin DSL
see full worked example [here: GitHub daggerok/spring-fu-jafu-example buildSrc/src/main/java/Globals.kt](https://github.com/daggerok/spring-fu-jafu-example/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/java/Globals.kt)