# Why is Gradle ignoring groupId/artifactId?

Tags: gradle

Here is my Gradle build:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'myorg'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

task createPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId group
            artifactId "myapp"
            version version
        }
    }.writeTo("build/libs/pom.xml")
}
```

And the build invocation I am using:

```
gradle clean build groovydoc sourcesJar createPom -Pversion=SNAPSHOT
```

When I run this:

- The POM file is created with `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` all appearing correctly inside the XML; but
- The name of the resultant JAR is whatever folder the project is rooted under. For instance, if the name of my project root is "fizz", and the buildfile above is located at `fizz/build.gradle`, then the build invocation above produces `fizz-<version>.jar` (where `<version>` is whatever value I specify on the command line). If I now rename the `fizz/` directory to `buzz/` and re-run the same build invocation, a `buzz-<version>.jar` will be produced.

My question: **how/where (what file) do I hardcode `groupId` and `artifactId` inside so that `myapp-<version>.jar` gets built, regardless of the name of the project root directory?**

Comment: It seems that here You can find what You're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262856/gradle-how-to-set-the-project-name-group-version-plus-source-targetcompatibi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a `settings.gradle` in the project root and inside you set the `rootProject.name = 'artifactId'` this will fix the name of the project.

The groupId and version can be set in the build.gradle file via the `group` and `version` properties.

Comment: Thanks @Leonard Brunings (+1) - however please see my changes (above). When I open up the generated `pom.xml` file, I see `groupId` as `null`. What can I do to correct this? Thanks again!

Comment: If you look at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sec:maven_pom_generation you see that you don't need to overwrite the properties in your pom at all since they default to your project properties.