# Using Gradle to include my own Java library in a project

Tags: java, gradle

Disclaimer: I'm very new to Gradle and Dependency Management. I tried reading the documentation but just couldn't get through the sheer amount of information. I also couldn't find anything useful to answer my question, so sorry if this has been answered before, I tried searching...

So my situation is as follows: I have one Java project that's supposed to give me a standardized way of using program configurations using JSON files. This project has a dependency on Gson. So far so good, I simply added `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'` to that projects dependencies and all's fine, the library shows up as External Library in Idea, and I can use it and stuff.

Now I want to use that project in other projects to make use of the configuration stuff. And I can not for the life of me figure out how to add the project or the library jar to other projects using Gradle.

I tried things like copying the library jar to the libs folder of the projects to use it in and adding `compile files('./libs/myLibrary-0.0.1.jar')` to the dependencies list, or adding the jar as a library via the Project Structure thing in Idea. None of these methods worked, and I'm at my wits end.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you or your company have a central binary repository, such as [artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/). Then you should set up publishing your jar there.

But since you haven't mentioned a central repository, I'll assume that you don't have one, and are simply trying to get your dependency to work on a single machine. In that case, what I suggest doing is this:

Add the maven-publish plugin to your dependency project:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

Also make sure that you define the `group`, `version` and `name` variables of your project (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262856/gradle-how-to-set-the-project-name-group-version-plus-source-targetcompatibi)). You'll need them later. Then add a publishing definition that will tell maven-publish to publish all classes:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Using these settings you should now be able to run the `publishToMavenLocal` task. Do it. If successful, the dependency jar should now be in your local maven repository (~/.m2/repository)

Now, add `mavenLocal` as a repository in the project that needs the dependency:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

(you might want to add additional repositories here, such as mavenCentral())

Also add your jar's group, name, and version just like your gson dependency:
`compile 'yourgrou:yourname:yourversion`.
Gradle should now be able to fetch the dependency from the local maven repo.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of options. First and easy is to build your base project and available in your local maven repository and use it. To make your project available is your local maven repo, use `maven` plugin. In your `build.gradle` file, add the following.

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Now use `gradle clean build install` to publish the jar to your local repo. Remember that `install` task is the one actually put your jar into your local.Then head over to your other project which depends on this one and tell it to look into your local maven repo by adding `mavenLocal` to the repositories.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Another option is, if you are using centralized repo in your company, you can publish your base jar and use it in the other project. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html).